# is there any solution to convert the raw data into some categorized datasets

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, stata

I have a data set that has values like Hindi, hindi, hendi, English, Englsh, inglish, inglsh...so on. I want this data set to bifurcate into different datasets which will be having similar kinds of values. for example in this case two datasets; the first is having values Hindi, hindi, hendi and another consists of English, Englsh, inglish, inglsh.

Comment: Can you think of simple heuristik rules, by which you want to sort them?

Comment: What does the data set look like? This question is far too vague

Comment: are there only those two groups?

Comment: This is just an example, the number of groups and unique values are unknown. The original data consist of millions of records.

Comment: On the information here, looking for `sh` and `nd` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can can use [`difflib.get_close_matches`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches)

Input:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['Hindi', 'hindi', 'hendi', 'English', 'Englsh', 'inglish', 'inglsh'])
>>> s
0   Hindi
1   hindi
2   hendi
3   English
4   Englsh
5   inglish
6   inglsh
```

processing:

```
import difflib
s.apply(lambda s: difflib.get_close_matches(s, possibilities=['english', 'hindi'])[0])
```

output:

```
0   hindi
1   hindi
2   hindi
3   english
4   english
5   english
6   english
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the unique values are small and known, you can try scoring a word with all the unique values and assign the word to the dataset whose unique value scores the highest.

There's a number of scoring mechanisms you can try here, like Levenshtein distance.

For example:

```
dataset = ['hindi', 'hundi', 'hendi', 'inglish', 'english', 'englesh']
unique_values = ['hindi', 'english']

segregated_dataset = {'hindi': [], 'english': []}

for val in dataset:
    max_score = 0
    for unique_val in unique_values:
        score = scoring_function(val, unique_val) # implement the scoring function of your choice
        if score > max_score:
            field = unique_val
            max_score = score
            
    segregated_dataset[field].append(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the correct set of required words are unknown, one possible answer to your ques might be in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups).

Its better to convert your words into lowercase using `numpy.char.lower(list_of_word)`